# what is the correct map with regexp in nginx?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I want to use different builds depends of browser version and device.
For example in "mobile chrome/80+ version" I need to have `modern-bundle` and on lower versions - `legacy-bundle`. Bur modern version for desktop is lower than for mobile: "chrome/70+ version" must have `modern-bundle` and on lower than 70 - `legacy-bundle`

I tried this code with two maps but finally I always have `legacy-bundle` instead of `modern-bundle`
What's wrong there?

```
map $http_user_request $is_mobile {
    default         false;
    "~*Mobile"      true;
}

map "$http_user_request:$is_mobile" $modern_browser {
    default     "";
    "~Chrome\/([8-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\.:true"       "modern-bundle";
    "~Chrome\/([7-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\.:false"      "modern-bundle";
}
```

Comment: I want give modern-bundle for mobile from 80 to 99. And for desktop is from 70 to 99

Comment: I mean `Chrome\/([8-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\.:true` transform to `Chrome\/([8-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\.Mobile` and will have modern-bundle. And lower **Mobile** versions will have legacy-bundle. The difference between mobile and desktop is 10 version - Mobile Chrome/70 must have legacy-bundle, but desktop Chrome/70 is modern-bundle. That is my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question. Just needed to add one more variable to map

```
map $http_user_request $is_mobile {
    default         false;
    "~Mobile"       true;
}

map "$http_user_request:$is_mobile:$http_user_request" $modern_browser {
    default     "";
    "~Chrome\/([8-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\..*:true:"       "modern-bundle";
    "~Chrome\/([7-9][0-9]|\d{3,})\..*:false:"      "modern-bundle";
}
```